# Can I use spring for idempotent injection?

Tags: java, spring

I have `UserService` and method `save(User user)`, which just saves users to a list. Can I use spring to call such method?

```
      <bean
            id="user_service"
            class="my.package.here.UserService">
        <property name="save">
            <bean class="my.package.here.User">
                <property name="email" value="my@email.com"/>
                <property name="firstName" value="Foo"/>
                <property name="lastName" value="Bar"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I tried this code and received `org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException`. I know that I can set a `List` of `users` straight forward. Anyway could you explain me the philosophy why cannot I inject something to `save` method?

Comment: save is a method, not a property. You can achieved your purpose declaring a member User and a method setUser in UserService. You can invoke methods on a bean via the configuration file but not that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring DI is build around JavaBeans concept.

> A JavaBean is a POJO that is serializable, has a no-argument constructor, and allows access to properties using getter and setter methods that follow a simple naming convention. Because of this convention, simple declarative references can be made to the properties of arbitrary JavaBeans.

So if you want to inject something into "property" `save` your class must have at least setter method, i.e. `setSave(User user)`. 

But what you are trying to do is against spring philosophy.